# .ajax() isn't posting to php database query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This has been an ongoing issue for me. You all have already helped so much. However, I am stuck again. I cannot get my `.ajax()` to run. For some reason the `.click()` won't even work without `if(field != text)` above my `.ajax()` call, but I digress.

My question is: Why is my `ajax()` not functioning properly and if this gets fixed will the table is have displayed update after the query is sent to the database without a page refresh?

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".edit_td").click(function()
        {
            $(this).children(".text").hide();
            $(this).children(".editbox").show();

        }).children('.editbox').change(function()
            {
                var id=$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
                var field=$(this).data('field');
                var text=$(this).val();

                var dataString = 'id= '+ id +'&field= '+ field +'&text= '+ text;
                alert("made variables");

                if(field != text)
                {
                    alert("in if");
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "table_edit_ajax.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        $("#first_"+ID).html(first);
                        $("#last_"+ID).html(last);
                    }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Enter something.');
                }
            });

        // Edit input box click action
        $(".editbox").mouseup(function() 
        {
            return false
        });

        // Outside click action
        $(document).mouseup(function()
        {
            $(".editbox").hide();
            $(".text").show();
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Here is my table_edit_ajax.php

```
<?php
   //connect to DB
   $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

   echo 'in table_edit';

   $id = mysqli_escape_String($_POST['id']);
   $table = "owners";
   $field = mysqli_escape_String($_POST['field']);
   $text = mysqli_escape_String($_POST['text']);
   $query = "UPDATE ".$table." SET ".$field."='".$text."' WHERE ".$table."_id = '".$id."'";
   mysqli_query($query);

   //close connection
   mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: You're missing the first argument to `mysqli_escape_string()`.

Comment: But it would be better if you used prepared queries with placeholders, instead of interpolating strings into the query.

Comment: Also, escaping should only be done for string values, not column names.

Comment: Create a simple form (in a new PHP page) that `post`s to `table_edit_ajax.php`, then try echoing out the `$query`. Run that query on your `mysql` console to see what the problem is.

Comment: Also, use a live AJAX debugging tool to see if you are sending the right parameters, and what your HTTP response code is. It should be 200. For Firefox, this is Firebug; other browsers have their own live debugging tools.

Comment: what is first and last in success callback??

Comment: Thanks @Barmar I am not even getting into the .php, though. The first and last in `success:` are things from a code snippet I never deleted. The data isn't `post`ing otherwise I'd see my echo, right?

Comment: Since your callback function doesn't display `html` anywhere, you won't see your echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to all mysqli functions is the connection, statement, or result object.

```
$id = mysqli_escape_String($con, $_POST['id']);
$table = "owners";
$field = $_POST['field'];
$text = mysqli_escape_String($con, $_POST['text']);
$query = "UPDATE ".$table." SET ".$field."='".$text."' WHERE ".$table."_id = '".$id."'";
mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

`$field` shouldn't be escaped, since it's not a string value. Therefore, you need to validate it carefully, to prevent SQL injection. Perhaps instead of allowing the client to submit the field name to update, have them submit an integer, which you look up in an array to convert to a field name.

In your AJAX call, you may have a problem due to not encoding your parameters properly. Change the `dataString` assignment to:

```
var dataString = { id: id, field: field, text: text };
```

Then jQuery will encode it for you.

Comment: Thanks, but my post isn't succeeding. Why? I changed my `success:` to `$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "table_edit_ajax.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html)
      {
       alert("IT WORKED!");
      }
      });`

Comment: I'm confused. If this didn't solve the problem, why is it accepted?

Comment: The odd thing is, when I do that my click event no longer works.

Comment: Then you did it wrong, since there's no reason that should prevent it from working. Are you getting any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: I accidentally put a `;` instead of `,` after `dataString`. The click event works again. I still am not getting any updates to my database, though. I get the success message, which is promising. Thanks for all your help. My php code is the only hindrance now I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

you are sending a data string

```
 var dataString = 'id= '+ id +'&field= '+ field +'&text= '+ text;
```

and retrieving it through $_POST.

first check what is in $_POST 
and use $_GET instead of $_POST

and change **post** in ajax to **get**

and what is first and last in success callback??